# Regex to exclude a specific string followed by a .*

Tags: regex

I'm having some problems with a RegEx.

I have this sample text:

> ICareCustomerBillingUI|Frontends|MVC|Pages|CreditdsAdjustments|cctor:Average Response Time (ms)
>       ICareCustomerBillingUI|Frontends|MVC|Pages|blabla|cctor:Average Response Time (ms)
>       ICareCustomerBillingUI|Frontends|MVC|Pages|blabla|mais1:Average Response Time (ms)
>       ICareCustomerBillingUI|Frontends|MVC|Pages|blabla|cctor|Called Backends|webservice at http//test:Average Response Time (ms)

I'm trying to exclude the lines with "Called Backends", but the problem is that there are various possible strings before.

I'm trying with:

> ICareCustomerBillingUI\|Frontends\|MVC\|Pages\|.*\|.*\|(?!Called Backends\|).*:Average Response Time (ms)

But this is returning the line I want to exclude.

Could you please help me?

Comment: It's probably a lot easier to write a regex to match any line that contains "Called Backends", then re-write the logic to exclude any line that matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below regex,

```
^ICareCustomerBillingUI\|Frontends\|MVC\|Pages\|[^|]*\|(?:(?!Called Backends\|).)*?:Average Response Time \(ms\)$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mR2rE1/2)

OR

```
^ICareCustomerBillingUI\|Frontends\|MVC\|Pages\|[^|]*\|(?!.*?Called Backends\|).*$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/mR2rE1/3)

Comment: Is there any regex question you are not answering ? :)

Comment: That was fast! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!.*?Called Backends\|).*$
```

Use this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/kM7rT8/11

Comment: @AvinashRaj the line should not have `Called backends` and that's it is what OP requires.

Comment: if that's the need then why op puts the negative lookahead at a specific part ?. `ICareCustomerBillingUI\|Frontends\|MVC\|Pages\|.*\|.*\|(?!Called Backends\|).*`

Answer (score 1):

Include the `|` in the lookahead:

```
^ICareCustomerBillingUI\|Frontends\|MVC\|Pages\|(?!.*\|Called Backends\|).*:Average Response Time \(ms\)
//                                          here __^^^^
```

Comment: So, I wasn't that far from the solution also. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I missed to escape the parenthesis arround `ms`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Right ;-)